# How to add an overlay to a MapKit Map View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I add an MKOverlay (MKTileOverlay, PolygonOverlay etc.) to a [Map View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map)?

My ContentView.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct City: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var cities: [City] = [
    City(coordinate: .init(latitude: 54.8985, longitude: 23.9036)),
    City(coordinate: .init(latitude: 54.6872, longitude: 25.2797)),
    City(coordinate: .init(latitude: 55.7033, longitude: 21.1443))
  ]
  @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.8, longitude: 23.8),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(
      latitudeDelta: 5,
      longitudeDelta: 5
    )
  )
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Map(
        coordinateRegion: $region,
        annotationItems: cities
      ) { city in
        MapPin(coordinate: city.coordinate, tint: .red)
      }.ignoresSafeArea()
      Circle()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .opacity(0.3)
        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
      VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
          Spacer()
          Button {
            self.cities.append(City(coordinate: self.region.center))
          } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
          }
          .padding()
          .background(.black.opacity(0.75))
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(.title)
          .clipShape(Circle())
          .padding(.trailing)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found that you can add Overlays to a [MapView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview):

```swift
class MyController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var overlay:MKTileOverlay = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg");

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.addOverlay(overlay);
    }
    // ...
```

But this one seems somehow different from the Map View that I use. It seems that my Map View doesn't have arguments for overlay data to be bound to it.

Comment: You have to use the UIKit version the SwiftUI version isn’t that customizable